# Union function in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to know how UNION operator works if we have two relations with different size

Say for example, i have two files like below

file a.txt is below

```
232,surender
262,ranjith
```

file b.txt is below

```
100,kumar,chennai
200,dhiv,chennai
```

my pig script is

```
A = LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(id:int,name:chararray);
B = LOAD 'b.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(id:int,name:chararray,city:chararray);
C = UNION A,B;
dump C;
```

Now the question is in my output Do i get three atoms or two atoms?.
I am getting two atoms only. Why is it showing two atoms. city field is missed out.
Please  Can someone explain me on this.

I need output as

```
(232,surender,,)
(262,ranjith,,)
(100,kumar,chennai)
(200,dhiv,chennai)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to load the file a.txt in the following way

A = LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(id:int,name:chararray,city:chararray);